# Subdomains to Private IP's in a network

Tags: networking, dns, web, ip, dyndns

Is it possible to point two subdomains to a private ip on a network?

For example

website1.domain.com points to 192.168.1.100 in my private network

and

website2.domain.com points to 192.168.1.101 in my private network

Both these ips would be seperate machines.

Is this possible using a service like dyndns and using their client?

Can this be done on the router connecting it to a service such as dyndns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure dynamic dns service to point to your router (e.g router.domain.com), and then configure the router to forward ports 80 and 8080 (you can choose any other 2 available ports) to your internal networks.

So, router.domain.com -> 192.168.1.100 
and router.domain.com:8080 -> 192.168.1.101.